# Split dataset to train and test for a LDA model

Tags: dataset, cross-validation, training-data, lda, train-test-split

I have a dataset that contains about 17000 of user data scraped from twitter and I am working with the latent dirichlet allocation algorithm. I want to split my dataset but I am not sure what is the best way.
What are the criteria to split a dataset when it comes to train a LDA model.
I am using gensim to train LDA model.
Thank you

Comment: It is tricky with unsupervised learning. Some good info in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162402/lda-topic-modeling-training-and-testing

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, it's useful